# Arduino based temperature sensing circuit

Tags: serial, led, voltage-level, communication, temperature-sensor

I've currently got a setup where I am using a 2 thermocouple setup using MAX31850 and the circuit looks exactly as mentioned here using the external power option. (https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-1-wire-thermocouple-amplifier-max31850k/wiring-and-test)

I take the data that is returned from this over serial and pass it over to a simple inverter circuit, which inverts the signal and fluctuates the voltage of a small CREE LED.
The problem that I am encountering is that the data being received from the thermocouples is incorrect when the LED is attached to the setup. And it becomes correct as soon as the LED is detached.

- I have tried running my thermocouple set up over an external 5V
  supply and using common ground with the Arduino, but it still does
  not help.
- I have tried using decoupling capacitors on the power rails
  to remove any noise due to the LED, but again to no help. What else
  can I try to ensure that I can read the data and modulate the LED
  simultaneously?

Comment: The question doesn't include details that would allow someone to replicate the problem and find out its cause.  "A simple inverter circuit" is vague.  Complete electrical schematics and some photos indicating layouts would improve the question.   ¶ You might try using optical isolators to transmit control signals, and run the LED with a separate battery.